# TypeError: Cannot find function getSheetbyName in object Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Some quick background - I'm not overly familiar with javascript or the implementation that seems to exist for use with Google Scripts, so please explain any suggested solutions clearly.

Anyway, I'm having an issue where my script cannot find the getSheetByName function. Now, this specifically occurs when I run it from my spreadsheet, but not from the script editor.

The section of code that throws the error is as follows (and no, I'm unable to share the specific sheet due to security policies):

```
function Refresh_materials() {
//Calls sheets, ranges, and last rows for later use
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
Logger.log(ss);
var Materials = ss.getSheetByName("Materials");
Logger.log(Materials.getIndex());
```

When in a spreadsheet, my script errors out at line 5, with the aforementioned issue. However, when I access the log or the execution viewables within the script editor, everything proceeds smoothly, and no error is throw. The log returns in this example:

```
[17-06-14 08:50:45:848 PDT] Spreadsheet
[17-06-14 08:50:45:952 PDT] 7.0
```

This is exactly what I would expect, as the sheet "Materials" is located at Index 7.

Seems to work great in the script editor, but consistently fails within the spreadsheet. I read up on an instance where a similar issue was only for a local user, and evidently disappeared given time.

Is there something incorrect with my script, or is there some other issue in play?

Thanks for the feedback.

-KS

Comment: How exactly do you run it from the spreadsheet? Do you use it as a custom function in a cell?

Comment: What is the line after `Logger.log(Materials.getIndex());`?

Comment: @AntonDementiev I have the script slaved to a button.

Comment: @Karl_S The script continues to initialize other variables, then goes into a for loop with if statements, each with their own further nested for loops.

I'll see about redacting information within the script and posting the entirety of it shortly.

Comment: try openById instead. getCurrentSpreadsheet likes to be a rebel sometimes.